# Can't install new Magento theme (using wamp loaclhost)

Tags: magento2, theme

I am using a localhost wamp server and have downloaded a theme, I have copied the zip file to my root folder and extracted as per the guide at https://zemez.io/magento/support/knowledge-base/step-3-upload-app-folder/
A bit unsure how to run commands using a wamp server

I need to do the following

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento index:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Bit of a novice sure not sure what to do, am I correct in thinking the path would be.

```
c:\wamp64\www\Magento\bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

or

```
C:\Users\mark>wamp64\www\Magento\bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: navigate to your magento root directory using "cd" and then execute "bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Comment: Try cmder ;-) and when case exists errors post again.

Comment: I am bit confused as new to using the Cmd, i open and C:\Users\mark> appears i type in :\Users\mark>wamp64\www\Magento\bin/magento setup:upgrade and the following error appears The system cannot find the path specified. I am obviously missing something but not sure what

Comment: type dir in terminal to list magento directories. you should be in root or in bin directory to run commands

Comment: -If you are in magento root directory run -> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
or
if you are in a bin directory run -> php magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I realise that potentially you are working around issues but more for reference and anyone else reading this but magento 2 is not supported on windows OS https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: Thanks Dominic, so to run a Magento site on a local server, would i have to have a PC with Ubuntu or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the root directory of the Magento.

You should be in the root directory of the Magento or in bin directory to run the Magento CLI commands.

You can use dir command in the terminal in Windows. (In Linux use ls)

Comment: now get this

C:\wamp64\www\Magento\bin>php magento setup:upgrade
Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
C:\wamp64\www\Magento\bin>php magento index:reindex
Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
C:\wamp64\www\Magento\bin>php magento cache:clean
Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
C:\wamp64\www\Magento\bin>